# Cache_Manager in View_Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have configured a Cachemanager Resource in my application.ini ... I can get this Resource from my Actions. Now I am trying to get the same Resource from a View_Helper and it's just not working! I'm getting my Zend_Cache_Manager Object ... but

```
$cachemanager->getCache('theresourcename');
```

is returning NULL...?

Any Ideas?

Best wishes, Alex

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
$resource = $bootstrap->getResource('cacheManager');
$cache = $resource->getCache('theresourcename');
```